Masorah parva hapax legomenon
Is there a complete listing of hapax legomenon in the Masorah parva in the Hebrew Old Testament as indicated by the hebrew letter ל with a small dot over it?

I actually think this question would be better answered on Judaism SE

Thanks Avi, I just posted it there!

This has a good answer and questions about hermeneutic methods and tools are on topic so I am voting to leave this open.

For those not familiar with hapax legomena:
https://library.biblicalarchaeology.org/sidebar/the-masoretes-at-work-a-tradition-preserved/

The most frequent note in the little masorah is the Hebrew letter
lamed (l) with a dot above it, which is an abbreviation for an Aramaic
word meaning “there are none”—meaning that this exact form of the word
is its only appearance in the biblical text (a hapax legomenon). One
such unique word, wmzjay, meaning “will seize them,” appears in line
2. The word also has a dot above it, which keys it to the relevant marginal note. (The word and note are highlighted in red.)

An example of the symbol for hapax legomenon in BHS:
https://www.ancientjewreview.com/read/2020/9/11/introduction-to-the-masorah-the-masorah-of-the-leningrad-codex-in-the-biblia-hebraica-stuttgartensia-bhs-edition

Here is a list I found in 2023 of both Hebrew and Greek hapax legomena -- https://community.logos.com/forums/t/70793.aspx
EDIT: Removed Dropbox link and added original internet source. The highlighted yellow areas are the downloads.

Not being a scholar, I don't know how accurate the list is. In any case, it may be a start for your inquiry.

Thanks for all the links providing a thorough and clear analysis of material that can be overwhelming. I actually ordered a copy of VETERIS TESTAMENTI Concordantiae Hebraicae Atque Chaldaicae for helping me nail down unique Hebrew forms.
